# Visual Studio 2012 proxy Authorization required

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am getting the Proxy Authorization failed error , inspite of adding the code 
`<system.net>`
`<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >`
`</defaultProxy>` 
`</system.net>`

to the web.config file..

can u please help me find out the probable reason.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIS_IUSRS is given authorization in IIS?

Try to bypass localhost.